# Calculate sentence from row to row in .txt file using vs code

Tags: python

I am doing the sentiment analysis. The initial code is just for a string. However, I want to make the program run and process the sentiment analysis for each sentence in a .csv file. The program is run using vs code.

Here is how I modified my code:

```py
fp = open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/hj.txt',encoding='utf-8' ,errors='ignore' ) # Open file on read mode
    lines = fp.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
    fp.close() # Close file
    print(lines)
    print("----------------------------------------------------\n")

    # simple example to tokenize paragraph into sentences for VADER
    from nltk import tokenize

    sentence_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(lines)
    paragraphSentiments = 0.0
    for sentence in sentence_list:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)

        print("{:-<69} {}".format(sentence, str(vs["compound"])))
        paragraphSentiments += vs["compound"]
    print("AVERAGE SENTIMENT FOR PARAGRAPH: \t" + str(round(paragraphSentiments / len(sentence_list), 4)))
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
```

I expect the output is sentiment analysis for each sentence in the .csv file. The errors I got are :

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 95, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1276, in <listcomp>
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 312, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1289, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `lines` is a list of strings, but `sent_tokenize()` is expecting a string.

You need something like:

```
for line in lines:
    sent_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(line)
    for sent in sent_list:
        # do your stuff
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The initial code is this:

```
paragraph = "It was one of the worst movies I've seen, despite good reviews. Unbelievably bad acting!! Poor direction. VERY poor production. The movie was bad. Very bad movie. VERY BAD movie!"


    from nltk import tokenize


    sentence_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(paragraph)
    paragraphSentiments = 0.0
    for sentence in sentence_list:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)
        print("{:-<69} {}".format(sentence, str(vs["compound"])))
        paragraphSentiments += vs["compound"]
    print("AVERAGE SENTIMENT FOR PARAGRAPH: \t" + str(round(paragraphSentiments / len(sentence_list), 4)))


print("{:-<69} {}".format(lines, str(vs["compound"])))
    paragraphSentiments += vs["compound"]
    print("AVERAGE SENTIMENT FOR PARAGRAPH: \t" + str(round(paragraphSentiments / len(sent_list), 4)))
```

I changed the code so it can read and do the sentiment analysis for each of the sentence in the .csv file. However, I hit with error. The modified code is as below:

```
    fp = open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/hj.txt',encoding='utf-8' ,errors='ignore' ) # Open file on read mode
    lines = fp.read().split("\n") # Create a list containing all lines
    fp.close() # Close file
    print(lines)

    from nltk import tokenize

    for line in lines:
        sent_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(lines)
        paragraphSentiments = 0.0
    for sent in sent_list:    

  sentence_list = tokenize.sent_tokenize(lines)
   paragraphSentiments = 0.0
   for sentence in sentence_list:
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(sentence)

       print("{:-<69} {}".format(sentence, str(vs["compound"])))
    #  paragraphSentiments += vs["compound"]
  print("AVERAGE SENTIMENT FOR PARAGRAPH: \t" + str(round(paragraphSentiments / len(sentence_list), 4)))
```

Anyone knows whats the issue here?